# IONIC Card layout styling seems not centered and not equally spaced

Tags: css, angular, ionic-framework, sass

I am building IONIC app and made a card layout as below.

```
<ion-content padding>
        <ion-card *ngFor="let book of booksData.books; let i=index">
              <ion-row>
                <ion-col col-3>
                    <ion-avatar item-start>
                    <img src="/../../img/authorImage.png">
                    </ion-avatar>
                </ion-col>
              <ion-col col-7>
                <ion-card-header>
                  #{‌{i+1}}
                </ion-card-header>
                  <ion-card-content>
                    <p>{‌{book.text}}</p>
                    <p>{‌{book.person}}</p>
                  </ion-card-content>
                </ion-col>
                <ion-col col-2>
                    <ion-row>
                    <ion-icon name="thumbs-up"></ion-icon>
                    </ion-row>
                    <ion-row>
                    <ion-icon name="thumbs-down"></ion-icon>
                    </ion-row>
                </ion-col>
                </ion-row>
                </ion-card>
</ion-content>
```

The card is splitted into three columns (as expected), how ever I am facing the below issue

The thumbs up and thumbs down icon are displaying but not taking the full available height . instead they are taking a fraction area of the column only. How can I make sure that the two icons take half the width of the Row of that specific column.

Any inputs on how to fix this please.

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a codepen with the code? it'll be easier to help.

Comment: I don't have it in codepen at the moment. Will try to create one and share it then. Thanks for looking into this. @GabrielBarreto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so this is how you can solve both your problems, here's the code for your page:

```
<ion-card *ngFor="let book of booksData.books; let i=index">
        <ion-row>
            <ion-col col-3>
                <ion-avatar item-start>
                    <img src="./assets/img/authorImage.png">
                </ion-avatar>
            </ion-col>
            <ion-col col-7>
                <ion-card-header>
                  #{‌{i+1}}
                </ion-card-header>
                <ion-card-content>
                    <p>{‌{book.text}}</p>
                    <p>{‌{book.person}}</p>
                </ion-card-content>
            </ion-col>
            <ion-col col-2>
                <ion-icon name="thumbs-up"></ion-icon>
                <ion-icon name="thumbs-down"></ion-icon>
            </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
</ion-card>
```

And this is the css for your page

```
.col[col-2] {
  display: grid;

  ion-icon {
    display: flex;
    font-size: 2em;
    align-self: center;
    justify-self: center;
  }
}
```

Let's go through the code:

For the image you'll need to add the path relative to your `index.html` file, since an Ionic app is simply an SPA (Single Page App) so every page is served as it was part of your `index.html`. The same works for images rendered though javascript files and CSS.

For your thumbs up buttons you first need to remove the rows from the HTML, they doesn't need to be inside of a row.

Then you can manipulate it with CSS, apply a `display: grid` to your col element with the `col-2` attribute, if you want you can change it to a class or ID and use something like `<ion-col col-2 class="thumbs-col">...</ion-col>` and change the CSS selector to `.thumbs-col` instead of `.col[col-2]`.

The display grid is enough to separate into 2 equal rows, but if by any reason it desn't separate this way just add `grid-auto-flow: row;` to your col selector.

For the icon i added a code so it can center the icon both vertically and horizontally with flexbox. For the size since the icon is not an image, but an SVG, you'll need to manipulate it's size with `font-size` and not `height/width`. If you change to a button with an icon, for an example, then you can use `height/width`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Wow , great explanation... Special thanks to your effort @Gabriel. This has provided me lot of information. I am able to see my image and the icons as I expected to see as well. Many thanks once again.